# Why do buckets created inside a Firebase cloud function don't appear in the console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a bucket from a cloud function like this:

return admin.storage().bucket(new_bucketName).create();

That works just fine, except that I can only see the new bucket in the storage browser (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=...) but not in the firebase console, unless I explicitly import it.

Is there a way to import it (or create it with the appropriate options, maybe I'm just missing something there) in code?

Comment: I'm going to ping your question to some in the Firebase team. I am able to repro this and would expect to see the same buckets listed either by `gsutil`, by Cloud Console and by Firebase Console.

Comment: OK. Chatted with Firebase engineering and they acknowledge the potential for confusion. This arises because of the need to assign (Firebase) security rules to (Cloud Storage) buckets before they can be used (by Firebase apps). Essentially, what you see in the Firebase Console (while a subset of resources) is the set of resources that are usable in Firebase apps. So, I recommend you file a Feature Request here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, I've just filed a FR.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase PM here,

Cloud Storage for Firebase allows developers to [link any Cloud Storage bucket](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage.html) to Firebase.

Concretely, "linking a bucket" means that Firebase adds permissions to that bucket to allow our SDKs to access those files--protected by [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/)

Because this action adds a second access channel with different authentication and authorization than the standard GCS auth mechanisms (of which [there are many](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/)), we don't automatically perform this for all GCS buckets.

The typical GCP project contains a number of different buckets for storing source code, built container images, ML models or training data, test lab videos, etc. that developers likely don't want exposed or accessible through Firebase SDKs, therefore we opted to keep these buckets unlinked.

Today, all linking is done through the console, though we are investigating a Firebase "Admin API" that would perform these actions.